# Convert Oracle DATE to Unix-style time (seconds since 1906?)

Tags: sql, oracle, unix-timestamp

I need to convert an Oracle DATE value to a Unix style seconds-since-epoch-start value.

I've tried various combinations of Oracle's conversions such as:

```
select to_number(to_date('10/05/2019','mm/dd/yyyy')) from dual;
select to_number(to_timestamp(to_date('10/05/2019','mm/dd/yyyy')))  from dual;
select to_number(to_char(to_date('10/05/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'))) from dual;
```

Nothing seems to work.   Does anyone have an answer to this?

Comment: Usually Unix time is seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC - are you sure about 1906?

Comment: Usually UNIX time, in addition to being measured from 1 January 1970, is a timestamp WITH TIME ZONE. It doesn't make much sense to apply it to an oracle DATE value, which does not have time zone information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's number of seconds since Jan 01 1906, then:

```
SQL> select sysdate - date '1906-01-01' days,
  2        (sysdate - date '1906-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 unix_style
  3  from dual;

      DAYS UNIX_STYLE
---------- ----------
 41555,811 3590422068

SQL>
```

Why? Because - when you subtract two dates in Oracle, result is number of **days**. Then you have to multiply it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day), by 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour) and once again by 60 (as there are 60 seconds in a minute).

Of course, you could have multiplied it by 86400 (which is 24 * 60 * 60), but - former is difficult to understand while latter *shows* what's going on and why.

If - as Wernfried commented - date differs from the one you said, you'd just replace `date '1906-01-01'` with `date '1970-01-01'`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.